# How to check if widget has automatic title

Tags: widgets

Some [default widgets](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L815)
 has automatic titles.

Is it possible to check if widget has automatic/inserted title using `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter?

Comment: I can tell you how to address the sample case but I am not sure there is a generic solution.

Comment: Is there anything I can do with `add_filter('widget_title', '')`?

Comment: Yes, that is filter I was looking at but I can't write that code right now.

Comment: Hope you write it soon. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any widgets written to operate as the Core "Recent Posts" widget does can be forced to skip the title by a filter on `widget_title`:

```
function widget_title_hack_191120($title, $instance) {
  if (empty($instance['title'])) {
    $title = '';
  }
  return $title;
}
add_filter('widget_title','widget_title_hack_191120', 10, 2);
```

I don't know if there is a generic solution to the problem. Any widget could avoid this simply by not using the `widget_title` filter.

Comment: Thank you! This saved the day! Actually I tried this last night but I was getting `Warning: Missing argument 2 for...` error. Looks like I had to add priority to the filter.

Comment: Actually, I'm still getting this error for some widgets added by plugins.

Comment: I was very clear that this will work with widgets like the core ones but that I don't think there is a generic solution. I can write widgets in at least two ways that will get around this.

Comment: Please do it. I need get this widgets thing done.

Comment: 1) What is not clear about ***"there is no generic solution"***? I can't write code to make this work with every widget out there. I said that from the beginning. **I know at least two ways to write a widget that will make it difficult or impossible to hack the title the way you want.** 2) You want me to fix errors caused by "some widgets added by plugins"? I don't even know what plugins are causing the issue and you want me to fix it? Does that even make sense to you? 3) I am here as a volunteer and that sounded like an order.

Comment: I apologize for this misunderstanding. I didn't intend to make it sound like an order. Anyway, thanks a lot for what you've helped me with till now. Much appreciated.